# Get the original menu item name string instead of the label

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, menus

I am building a hierarchical menu of custom taxonomies and their related posts using wp_get_nav_menu_items as follow:

```
if( $locations = get_nav_menu_locations() && isset($locations['secondary']) ):
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['secondary'] );

  $menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->term_id );

  foreach( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ):
    # access to $menu_item -> title;
    # access to $menu_item -> ID;
    # access to $menu_item -> object_id;
    # etc ...
  endforeach;
endif;
etc ...
```

Say I have a menu item called **service** (it is a term of custom taxonomy solutions_category), and from the Appearance -> Menus I changed its label to '**Our Services**' through the Navigation Label. In this case **$menu_item->title** returns 'Our Services'. How can I get 'service' instead? Because I need it for a subsequent WP_Query to get all posts that belong to custom category 'service'

Thanks

P.S. I can post full code if you need.

Comment: Have you tried doing a `var_dump()` on one of your `$menu_item`'s? I suspect that somewhere in that object will be what you're after. There's a lot of info in the [Return Values](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items#Return_Values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get that information by using the `get_term_by()` function with the relevant parameters of the menu item (namely `object` and `object_id`) :

```
foreach( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item )
{
    // Match the menu items to your custom taxonomy:
    if( 'solutions_category' === $menu_item->object )
    {
        // Fetch the corresponding term object:
        $term = get_term_by( 'term_id', $menu_item->object_id, $menu_item->object );

        // Show the term name:
        echo $term->name;

        // Debug:
        // print_r( $term );
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't want to target a special taxonomy, you can replace

```
    // Match your custom taxonomy:
    if( 'solutions_category' === $menu_item->object )
```

with

```
    // Match only menu items of the type "taxonomy":
    if( 'taxonomy' === $menu_item->type )
```

where  `$menu_item->type` can have values like `taxonomy`, `post_type`, `custom` (Links), `...`

The value of `$menu_item->type_label` gives you also further information on the menu item type.

Hope this help.